# Downvoting systematically a user

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

I have got 8 downvotes in the last 2 days, on various questions and answers. Clearly someone is mad at me... Is there any way to stop that? Thanks!

Comment: If someone has been naughtty, the software will catch it, and undo the downvotes. See, e.g., https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3685/serial-downvoting

Comment: Only if it happens fast enough.  I suspect I've been targeted by someone for my behavior, and have received a slow and steady succession of downvotes.  Fortunately I'm learning to disregard down votes.  Gerhard "Reputation Comes In Many Flavors"  Paseman, 2020.07.27.

Comment: Apparently the software is on holiday... Of course I don't care about the downvotes, it is just that I find the behaviour of the downvoter quite inappropriate.

Comment: I think I might know who it is. I'll see about getting this sorted out. (Edit: I've sent a message to Community Management, who presumably will get back to us shortly. Hopefully the downvotes will be invalidated soon.)

Comment: They have been indeed, thanks very much. I hope that the downvoter has been informed that this kind of behaviour is unacceptable.

Answer (score 9):

The rash of downvotes was picked up by the software and was reversed, and I have just learned from a Community Manager of other voting anomalies. All of these have been fixed, and a moderator message was sent warning against targeted voting, and reminding that voting should be based on the merits of the post, and not the person/account posting it.

Comment: Thanks so much again! The system, and the moderators, are remarkably efficient.